# Appium does not find element until it is tapped on mobile device. How to find element for which it does not have focus?

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, appium

I am new for automation testing.
I am trying to automate UI and want to tap on humburger menu.

I tried it with

```
1. MobileElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc='" + "Menu" + "']"));
    el1.click();
2. MobileElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.name("Menu)"));
    el1.click();
3. MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc=\"Menu\"]");
```

in all the cases i got error for element not found.

But when i tap manually on menu within test befor el1.click() get executed then test get run successfully. It is just like menu element get focused and appium find it.
So how to execute this without tap or getting focus?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the element by its name. In UI Inspector search before with name or any other locator. If it searches successfully with few attempts. Sometimes element has dynamic identification.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your code again but this time set the capability `automationName` to `uiautomator2`? Your problem sounds like the ones I have sometimes and moving from UIA1 to UIA2 (uiautomator2) solved that. UIA2 is however a bit more slow detecting elements IMO.